# Zend Framework: 'Cannot nest headScript captures'

Tags: php, zend-framework

iam using ZF 1.11.x on my local machine (osx) everything works like excepted, but when i deploy my application to the production server an error occures:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container_Exception' with message
>   'Cannot nest headScript captures' in
>   /var/www/virtual/website/library/Zend/View/Helper/HeadScript.php:146

Iam using the viewHelper to set some variables inside my layout.phtml. I can fix it by putting them just in script tags but i like to know why this error happens..

Comment: show some code on what fixes it

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code [here](http://www.phpkode.com/source/p/tomatocms/libraries/Zend/View/Helper/HeadScript.php) this exception happens when you try to nest `captureStart()` calls.

Since it doesn't happen locally I suspect that your provider/production server has been setup in a specific manner - which often is the case when you don't use a dedicated root server...

Answer (score 0):

For us, this problem was caused due to short tags not being enabled for PHP.

**Edit your php.ini, change "short_open_tag" to "on"**

Basically we were using the following to end capture.

```
<?
$this->inlineScript()->captureEnd();
?>
```

But if short tags aren't enabled, this wont be recognized and any subsequent call of $this->inlineScript()->captureStart(); will crash.